# Selecting one random data from a column from multiple rows in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, random, greatest-n-per-group

I am creating a view that needs to select only one random row for each customer. Something like:

```
select c.name, p.number
from customers c, phone_numbers p
where p.customer_id = c.id
```

If this query returns:

```
NAME      NUMBER
--------- ------
Customer1 1
Customer1 2
Customer1 3
Customer2 4
Customer2 5
Customer3 6
```

I need it to be something like:

```
NAME      NUMBER
--------- ------
Customer1 1
Customer2 4
Customer3 6
```

Rownum wont work because it will select only the first from all 6 records, and i need the first from each customer. I need solution that won't affect performance much, because the query that selects the data is pretty complex, this is just an example to explain what I need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually mean 'random', or 'any' - does it matter if you might get the same number for a customer each time you query the view? Getting an arbitrary row would be faster than a random one as you could avoid the call to `dbms_random`.

Comment: Either way. Any would do as well. It just has to be exactly one number, no matter if the customer has 1 or 1000, and it doesn't matter which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT name,
       number
FROM   (
  SELECT c.name,
         p.number,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ) AS rn
  FROM   customers c
         INNER JOIN phone_numbers p
         ON ( p.customer_id = c.id )
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Even though the performance is affected quite a bit in my case, I'm sure I can optimize the query.

Comment: @Paul If you just want a single row then you could use `ORDER BY ROWNUM` instead of using `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` - that may speed the query up but it will (probably) not be random.

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by clause to return only one phone number:

```
select c.name, MAX(p.number) as phone
from customers c, phone_numbers p
where p.customer_id = c.id
group by c.name
```

Comment: This will get a specific row (the maximum value) rather than a random row as the OP requested. You could use `MAX( p.number ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE )` instead.

Comment: I thought that by "random" he meant "any" because later he says "and i need the first from each customer".

Comment: It doesnt matter, it has to have at least one number shown, it doesnt matter which one :)

Comment: That's what I understood, so MAX would be the simplest and best performing solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the min or max aggregate function with [the `keep dense_rank` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm):

```
select c.name,
  min(p.number) keep (dense_rank last order by dbms_random.value) as number
from customers c
join phone_numbers p on p.customer_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
order by c.name;
```

(`number` isn't a valid column or alias name as it's a reserved word, so use your own real name of course).

If the phone number needs to be arbitrary rather than actually random, you can order by something else:

```
select c.name,
  min(p.number) keep (dense_rank last order by null) as number
from customers c
join phone_numbers p on p.customer_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
order by c.name;
```

You'll probably get the same number back for each customer each time, but not always, and data/stats/plan changes will affect which you see. It seems like you don't care though. But then, using a plain aggregate might work just as well for you, as in @under's answer.

If you're getting lots of columns from that random row, rather than just the phone number, MTO's subquery might be simpler; for one or two values I find this a bit clearer though.