# Oracle - Combine timestamp with date and remove duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB, which gives me the timestamp and the date in several columns.

"JDDate" as the date, "END" as the end time, and "START" as the start.

The date is thus output in the format CYYDDD, the time in the format HHMMSS. With the following instruction I get the necessary formats:

```
SELECT
    DATE '1900-01-01' + FLOOR("JDDate" / 1000) * INTERVAL'1' YEAR+ (MOD("JDDate", 1000) -1) * INTERVAL'1' DAY AS "Date",
    LTRIM((SUBSTR("NR", -6)), '0') AS "Staff Nr",
    CASE WHEN "END" =240000 THEN '23:59:59' ELSE REPLACE(TO_CHAR("END", '00,00,00'),',',':') END AS "tEnd",
    REPLACE(TO_CHAR("START", '00,00,00'),',',':') AS "tStart",

FROM "POOLXX1"."CCD021"
WHERE   "JDDate" >118000
```

Now I want to somehow get the difference. Maybe you have to combine the date with the timestamp and calculate a difference accordingly.
There is a condition. If for each person (column "NR") for a day, the same start and end stamp are assigned, then these are duplicates. These should be disregarded accordingly.
Maybe it makes sense to use them before.

Do you need more information?

Best regards!
Joshua

Comment: My advice to you is to ditch this bad data model, and instead just use datetime/timestamp columns to store both the date and time together.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not possible. This is the only format to get this information/ data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your numeric (apparently) start/end time representations into fractions of days, or into intervals, and add those to your converted date. Presumably you actually want 240000 to really be midnight the following day, rather than one second before that, if you're doing calculations. So for example you could do:

```
select
    date '1900-01-01'
      + floor("JDDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
      + (mod("JDDate", 1000) -1) * interval '1' day
      + floor("START" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
      + floor(mod("START", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
      + mod("START", 100) * interval '1' second
      as start_datetime,
    date '1900-01-01'
      + floor("JDDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
      + (mod("JDDate", 1000) -1) * interval '1' day
      + case when "END" = 240000 then interval '1' day
             else floor("END" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
                + floor(mod("END", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
                + mod("END", 100) * interval '1' second
        end
      as end_datetime
from ccd021
where "JDDate" > 118000;
```

The calculations are basically the same, but the `END` one keeps the case expression - it just adds a full day for 240000 instead of an adjusted time.

If you have duplicates that you want to supress (and can't remove from the base data for some reason) then you can use `distinct`.

```
select distinct ltrim(substr(nr, -6), '0') as staff_nr,
    date '1900-01-01'
    + ...
```

I'd suggest you use those conversions, or something similar, as the base for all your display elements too - once you have those complete date values you can format them as strings however you want. For example:

```
with cte (staff_nr, start_datetime, end_datetime) as (
  select distinct ltrim(substr(nr, -6), '0'),
      date '1900-01-01'
        + floor("JDDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
        + (mod("JDDate", 1000) -1) * interval '1' day
        + floor("START" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
        + floor(mod("START", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
        + mod("START", 100) * interval '1' second,
      date '1900-01-01'
        + floor("JDDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
        + (mod("JDDate", 1000) -1) * interval '1' day
        + case when "END" = 240000 then interval '1' day
               else floor("END" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
                  + floor(mod("END", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
                  + mod("END", 100) * interval '1' second
          end
  from ccd021
  where "JDDate" > 118000
)
select staff_nr,
  to_char(start_datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as start_datetime,
  to_char(end_datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as end_datetime,
  end_datetime - start_datetime as diff_in_days,
  24 * (end_datetime - start_datetime) as diff_in_hours,
  cast(end_datetime as timestamp) - cast(start_datetime as timestamp) as diff_as_interval
from cte
where end_datetime != start_datetime;
```

... which also shows a filter to remove rows there start and end are the same.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e1a9cfe4b5fa3b7d9282719cb46f6ef)

(Well, really I'd suggest you rethink the data model, but that seems to not be possible... Even if you can't replace how data is stored now, you *might* be able to add additional virtual columns for the converted values, so you don't have to do the conversion yourself when you query.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your approach! Unfortunatelly, this is my second day working/ fighting with SQL. Respective I cant imolement  the Distinct Statement. How can  I manage  this? There are duplactes, based on all columns.

Comment: Why can't you use distinct? If entire rows in the result set are duplicated, that's exactly [what `distinct` does](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#d424000e2192).

Comment: Where do I put this Statement? Just behind Select, at your first code?

Comment: It's a keyword, not a statement. I've shown one example in the answer, and the db<>fiddle I linked to has distinct in both queries - showing a duplicate row being surpressed.

Comment: I am sry, I could not see it on my smartphone earlier. It works great! 
Is there a way to hide the days directly, where is the start = end time? And how would the SQL statement look if duplicates within JDDate, End & Starttime, and Nr are recognizable, but there are 7 columns in total? Would the DISTINCT work too?

Comment: If you're using the second version, with the CTE, from the fiddle; then you can just add a filter `where end_datetime != start_datetime`. If there are additional columns that are not identical, then you have to decide what you want to see - if you have three rows with the same nr/start/end, and the values in the other columns are different, then you either show all three, or define some criteria to decide which of the three to show.

Comment: Tanks Paul! Yes, I am using your code with CTE. Ohh cool, quite simple the "!=" operator. There are totally 7 columns. The columns above are just necessary for the right difference. There are also the columns "Order Nr", "Dep", and "Terminal". If there are duplicates, based on "Nr"/ "Staff Nr", "JDDate", "START", "END" and "Terminal", then just only one row should be displayed. No matter which one exactly.

Comment: This is getting a long way from your original question; but you can add a `row_number()` clause in the CTE, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44648623/266304), with the `partition by` including the 4/5 columns that are duplicated; then filter that in the main query.

Comment: Hey Alex, I have a lot to thank you! Unfortunately, it is a big challenge for me, to catch the syntax of SQL. I have never been programming or something like this. Where have I to put ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY  "Nr", "JDDate", "START", "END", "Terminal" ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ) AS rn ?

Comment: @joshua1990 - as an extra expression inside the CTE, in addition to all the other columns and calculated columns you're getting. I've added an example [to this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8358f0989e118912f084e59bf61f1883), using a `row_number()` filter instead of distinct, but I don't have all your other columns so you'll need to expand it.

Comment: Thanks! It works great Alex. CTE is an array, right? Now I want to display two more columns ("Order Nr" & "Dep") There are not necessary for the duplicates, but I need them too. I have tried this approch: cte (staff_nr, start_datetime, end_datetime, Order Nr, Dep) and after the row_number : "Order Nr", "Dep". But this is not working.

Comment: CTE is common table expression, or [subquery factoring[(https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#d424000e1638). Like I said, this is a long way from your original question. Adding columns to the CTE should be fairly simple, but if you can't figure it out then as a new question, including your table structure and best attempt at a query, and what doesn't work or what errors you get.

Comment: Thanks Alex! There will be a new question with all necessary information soon